# No Disks on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, startup

I have an early 2013 MacBook Pro 15.4" Retina. A few "crashes" happened and I ended up resetting my mac, deleting all files on the device. Now when it loads up it flashes a folder with a question mark. I am trying to reload the OS onto the device but it appears that I have no disk to select? When I boot into safe mode and click reinstall OS X, I have NO disk options. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What shows in Disk Utility?

Comment: "Reset" how, exactly?

Comment: Don't click to reinstall MacOS, click on Disk Utility to format the drive. If no drive shows up there may be an issue with the drive or the Mac itself